# How set value on dataframe given a variable number of conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, iterable-unpacking

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

animals = ["dogs", "cats"]
eyes = ['brown', 'blue', 'green']
height = ['short', 'average', 'tall']
a = [animals, eyes, height]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(*a)), columns=["animals", "eyes", "height"])
df['value'] = 1
```

Output:

```
   animals   eyes   height  value
0     dogs  brown    short      1
1     dogs  brown  average      1
2     dogs  brown     tall      1
3     dogs   blue    short      1
4     dogs   blue  average      1
5     dogs   blue     tall      1
6     dogs  green    short      1
```

Question:
How do I create a single function such that zeros "value" in one or many rows given one or many conditions?

Examples:

```
# This would change all the 1s into 0s for all dogs with blue eyes.
zero_out(df, [("animals", "dogs"), ("eyes", "blue")])

# This would change all the 1s into 0s for all tall animals.
zero_out(df, [("height", "tall")])
```

My attempts thus far:
I tried to do this with *unpacking but had no luck because I don't know how to set multiple conditions using unpacked variables. It's easy to set multiple conditions if I hardcode the number of conditions though...
`df[(condition1) & (condition2) & (condition3)] = 0`

Further, and perhaps this is outside the scope of the question, how can i set a variable number of conditions given a regular if statement using *unpacking (or without hardcoding the number of conditions in the if statement?

E.g.

```
if a > 0 and b > 4
#Or...
if a > 0 and b > 4 and c < 2
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query) method:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

animals = ["dogs", "cats"]
eyes = ['brown', 'blue', 'green']
height = ['short', 'average', 'tall']
a = [animals, eyes, height]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(*a)), columns=["animals", "eyes", "height"])
df['value'] = 1


def zero_out(df, lst):
    q = ' & '.join( '{} == "{}"'.format(col, val) for col, val in lst )
    df.loc[df.query(q).index, 'value'] = 0

zero_out(df, [("height", "tall")])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   animals   eyes   height  value
0     dogs  brown    short      1
1     dogs  brown  average      1
2     dogs  brown     tall      0
3     dogs   blue    short      1
4     dogs   blue  average      1
5     dogs   blue     tall      0
6     dogs  green    short      1
7     dogs  green  average      1
8     dogs  green     tall      0
9     cats  brown    short      1
10    cats  brown  average      1
11    cats  brown     tall      0
12    cats   blue    short      1
13    cats   blue  average      1
14    cats   blue     tall      0
15    cats  green    short      1
16    cats  green  average      1
17    cats  green     tall      0
```

---

Or `zero_out(df, [("animals", "dogs"), ("eyes", "blue")])`:

```
   animals   eyes   height  value
0     dogs  brown    short      1
1     dogs  brown  average      1
2     dogs  brown     tall      1
3     dogs   blue    short      0
4     dogs   blue  average      0
5     dogs   blue     tall      0
6     dogs  green    short      1
7     dogs  green  average      1
8     dogs  green     tall      1
9     cats  brown    short      1
10    cats  brown  average      1
11    cats  brown     tall      1
12    cats   blue    short      1
13    cats   blue  average      1
14    cats   blue     tall      1
15    cats  green    short      1
16    cats  green  average      1
17    cats  green     tall      1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def zero_out(df, list_of_filters, out_column='value'):
    conds = np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    for col_name, val in list_of_filters:
        cond = df[col_name].eq(val)
        conds &= cond
    df.loc[conds, out_column] = 0
    return df
```

You can alternatively use this. It's slightly more generic than Andrej's method in that it doesn't assume the filter values are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def zero_out(df, *args):
    df_temp = df.copy()
    for arg in args:
        df_temp = df_temp[df_temp[arg[0]] == arg[1]].copy()
    df.iloc[df_temp.index, -1] = 0
    return df

zero_out(df, ("animals", "dogs"), ("eyes", "blue"))
```

Result:

```
   animals   eyes   height  value
0     dogs  brown    short      0
1     dogs  brown  average      0
2     dogs  brown     tall      0
3     dogs   blue    short      0
4     dogs   blue  average      0
5     dogs   blue     tall      0
6     dogs  green    short      0
7     dogs  green  average      0
8     dogs  green     tall      0
9     cats  brown    short      1
10    cats  brown  average      1
11    cats  brown     tall      1
12    cats   blue    short      0
13    cats   blue  average      0
14    cats   blue     tall      0
15    cats  green    short      1
16    cats  green  average      1
17    cats  green     tall      1
```